# How can i change the device orientation on button click without rotating the device

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, iphone-developer-program, iosdeployment

i want to change the device orientation on button click without rotating the device.

**HERE IS MY CODE:**

```
-(void)funcLandscapeBtnTapped:(UIButton *)button
{ 
      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft animated:NO];
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: from above code, what should be happening ?

Comment: Nothing happening screen remains in portrait mode only.I want screen changes its orientaion to landscapeleft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code, its working,

Your's Button Action:

```
isEnablePortraidMode = true;
NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
NSNumber *StatusBarOrientation = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft];
[UIViewController attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation];
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:number forKey:@"orientation"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] performSelector:@selector(setStatusBarOrientation:) withObject:StatusBarOrientation];
[UIViewController attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation];
```

and Add this method in Appdelegate

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window{
    if(isEnablePortraidMode)
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
     }
    else
    {
         return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

**AppDelegate.h**

```
@property BOOL restrictRotation;
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
#define APPDELEGATE ((AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate])

- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask )application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {

    if (self.restrictRotation == YES) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;        
    }
    else {
        if (isiPhone || isiPod) {
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
        }else{
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
        }
    }
}
```

**YourViewController.m**

```
-(void)funcLandscapeBtnTapped:(UIButton *)button
{
    APPDELEGATE.restrictRotation = YES;
        [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:
         [NSNumber numberWithInteger: UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight]
                                    forKey:@"orientation"];
        [self shouldAutorotate];
}
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
    if ( orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight
        | orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
    {
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Now how can i get default full screen button action in AVPlayerviewcontroller? It comes when we showsPlaybackControls = true.